# removing certain duplicate lines while keeping others

Tags: awk

I am trying to remove most duplicate lines in a file(or piped output from a script function , to be more precise), but want to keep others containing a certain pattern.
Have seen here and elsewhere that

```
awk '!($1 in a){a[$1];print}' OR
awk '!x[$0]++'
```

work great IF you're seeking to simply remove every duplicate.
But can a condition easily be added to this mechanism?

For example,  I want to keep all lines where:

```
$1==".:"||$1==":."||$1==":"||$1="."
```

but, any other line, I would want to be sure is NOT duplicated.
So in the example below, I want to remove "/bin" and "/usr/bin".

```
/bin
:
/usr/bin
:
/usr/openwin/bin
:
/usr/bin
:
/usr/etc
:
/etc
:.
:
a
:
/usr/bin/X11
:
.
:
/bin
:
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
awk '!($1 in a) || ($1 == ":") || ($1 == ":.") || ($1 == ".:") || ($1 == ".") {a[$1];print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
awk '($1==".:"||$1==":."||$1==":"||$1="."||!x[$0]++)' $file
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: How is it not an answer? It is suggested awk command line that should solve the problem. Assuming it works correctly (it did in a quick test on my end) it is a correct one even. In what way is this less of an answer than the other two answers posted to this question?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '!seen[$0]++ || ($1 ~ /^(\.:|:\.|:|\./)$)' file     
/bin
:
/usr/bin
:
/usr/openwin/bin
:
:
/usr/etc
:
/etc
:.
:
a
:
/usr/bin/X11
:
.
:
:
```